# All-in-one web-administration tool, alternative to Webmin

Tags: software-recommendation, panel, administration, tools, webmin

Are there any good or possibly better alternatives for [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/index.html) ?. Basically I want to have one single application to monitor the entire Ubuntu system / network / ... , etc.

> **Webmin** is a web-based interface for system administration for Unix.
>   Using any modern web-browser, you can setup user accounts, Apache,
>   DNS, file sharing and much more. Webmin  removes the need to manually
>   edit Unix configuration files like `/etc/passwd`, and lets you manage a
>   system from the console or remotely. See the standard modules page for
>   a list of all the functions built into Webmin, or check out the
>   screenshots.

Comment: Can you please explain why you don't want to use webmin? What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 4):

I use Ajenti. Support is very well, too.
http://ajenti.org/

Comment: @pji the software is AGPL3 according to this page: http://ajenti.org/licensing. Why do you think it is not libre-free?

Answer (score 3):

There is something called Ebox. I've only heard good things about it. It's free software and it's in the archives. It has many modules for different things, like network. They've renamed it to Zentyal, but it's still called Ebox in the archives. You can read about it here: http://www.zentyal.org/

Comment: I tried install in ubuntu 11.04,throwing this error.
http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Documentation/Community/Installation/InstallationGuide?redirectedfrom=Document%2FDocumentation%2FInstallationGuide
Fetched 578 kB in 15s (37.5 kB/s)                                              
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zentyal/2.0/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/zentyal/2.0/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comparison on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_hosting_control_panels

Since answers which only contain a link get closed soon, I added a screenshot of the current wikipedia comparison:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://alternativeto.net/software/webmin/ lists a bunch, but watch the licensing, if it matters... many are commercial, freemium, or open source but not free-as-in-freedom.

Answer (score 0):

**DirectAdmin** is a relatively lightweight control panel that supports Linux. It has all of the basic features of a control panel, including support for multi-customer setups.

[image]

**Administrator features**

```
Create / Modify Admins and Resellers

Admins can create resellers or extra admins quickly and easily with this feature.
Reseller Packages

Admins can create predefined account packages using this feature. When creating an account, the admin simply chooses a package instead of manually setting each account feature.
Show All Users

This feature allows the admin to quickly view every single account on the system and sort this list in various ways.
DNS Administration

This feature allows the admin to create, modify, or delete any DNS records on the server.
IP Manager

This is where the admin sets the IP address available to the server. The admin can also allocate IP address to resellers from this menu.
Mail Queue Administration

Tool to view mail queue and it's messages. Includes tools to take action on those messages.
System / Services Info

The admin can view, stop, start, and restart services from this menu.
Complete Usage Statistics

This feature provides the admin with a complete overview of system usage. Exact input and output from the server's Ethernet card is also monitored.
DNS Clustering

DirectAdmin talks to other DirectAdmin machines to automatically transfer DNS data between them. It also has the ability to check the other server for a domain so as to not allow duplicate domains on your DA network.
SPAM fighting tools in DirectAdmin

A wide varienty of SPAM-fighting tools are provided with DirectAdmin. Please check http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=577 for a full list.
Licensing / Updates

The admin can view his or her license status and download the latest DirectAdmin security and software upgrades from this menu.
```

[Link DirectAdmin](https://www.directadmin.com/features_list.php)